# Missing ) after argument list. (line 11, file “Code”) for code to link google excel to google forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

We can really use some help. We are trying to Link a list on google excel to a drop down menu on google forms. The twist is that this google excel list will be continuously updated and needs to automatically populate on google forms. Im borrowing this code we found online It worked for the creator but Im having this error.

```
function updateLists() {
    var form = FormApp.openById(1aGrHm7x39kAJ-iJlFvp58saZHyARyB92uCbyvxGqE7M);
    var items = form.getItems();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
        for (var j = 0; j < LIST_DATA.length; j+=1) {
            var item = items[i]
            if (item.getTitle() === LIST_DATA[i].title){
                updateListChoices(item.asListItem(), LIST_DATA[i].sheet);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code at:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1apBDaQy3vL7O26dodf0OdK6NmI29omfB2KsV4T2B_tM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass a `string`:

```
var form = FormApp.openById("1aGrHm7x39kAJ-iJlFvp58saZHyARyB92uCbyvxGqE7M");
```

Or, since you already have the id in `FORMID`, just:

```
var form = FormApp.openById(FORMID);
```

However, the id of the spreadsheet you wanted is not that, it's this:

```
0AoFVL1CoqhmxdDE2UDRHbnBaNnAzUjVHLVFQcWQxSlE
```

So do this instead:

```
var form = FormApp.openById("0AoFVL1CoqhmxdDE2UDRHbnBaNnAzUjVHLVFQcWQxSlE");
```

Comment: I noticed that too, but why is it causing the error they get? BTW, it looks like that string is the value of the variable `FORMID`

Comment: When we use 

var form = FormApp.openById(FORMID);

We get this...No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 11, file "Code")

Comment: Nah, that means the current problem is solved. But your code cannot find an item with the ID you specified.

Comment: see here 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoFVL1CoqhmxdDE2UDRHbnBaNnAzUjVHLVFQcWQxSlE&usp=sharing

Comment: @user2954923 You're probably not authenticating to the API with a key that has access to that form, or the ID is wrong.

Comment: Sorry folks but we are still seeing errors https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoFVL1CoqhmxdDE2UDRHbnBaNnAzUjVHLVFQcWQxSlE&usp=sharing 

The link takes you to the document please check it out to see. We are getting Invalid ID (line 11, file "Code")